# How to clear or refresh Firebase Hosting Cache in React Project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I deploy my personal portfolio website. In my portfolio website, I attached a link that can download my resume in PDF. I regularly update my website when my resume is updated. The problem is when I use the google search engine and type my name, one of the links in the Google search engine will show my old resume. For example, the link will be something like this `www.my_name.com/81cc41fe4ff006a65f4742ca5acd7ffd.pdf` in the Google Search Engine.

I found out that this extension link `81cc41fe4ff006a65f4742ca5acd7ffd.pdf` is within the file `hosting.cHVibGlj.cache` of the `.firebase` folder.
[image]

I attempted to delete all the contents in the file `hosting.cHVibGlj.cache` and run `firebase deploy`, but then the same contents that I deleted came back.

I did some research online and people suggest adding the following script inside the `firebase.json` file.

```
    "headers": [
      { "source":"/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}] }
    ],
```

Now my updated `firebase.json` file is:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      { "source":"/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}] }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I run `firebase deploy`. However, I can still find my old resume in PDF on the Google search engine.

Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Comment: Cache-control is for browser, not for engines. Google crawler will crawl your website once a while, it didn't crawl your website after you change it, that's why you have old result. You can force it to crawl it and see new result. Google how to do it, or maybe someone will answer your question.

Comment: I believe I updated my resume a few hours ago. How do I force Google crawler to crawl my website to see the update?

Comment: I checked and I don't think that's the issue. Every time when I run `firebase deploy`, that hosting cache file will show up. Even if I create a new firebase project and deploy it. Same issue.